# Chrome performance: "standard" property names vs. non-standard

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome

So this is an interesting one... While I was testing the performance of setAttribute vs. normal property set on an element, I found an odd behavior, which I then tested on regular objects and... It's still odd!

So if you have an object `A = {}`,
and you set its property like `A['abc_def'] = 1`, or `A.abc_def = 1`, they are basically the same.
But then if you do `A['abc-def']` = 1 or `A['123-def']` = 1 then you are in trouble. It goes wayyy slower.
I set up a test here: http://jsfiddle.net/naPYL/1/. They all work the same on all browsers except chrome.
The funny thing is that for "abc_def" property, chrome is actually much faster than Firefox and IE, as I expected. But for "abc-def" it's at least twice as slow.

So what happens here basically (at least from my tests) is that when using "correct" syntax for properties (legal C syntax, which you can use with dot properties) - It's fast, but when you use syntax that requires using brackets (a[...]) then you're in trouble.

I tried to imagine what implementation detail would distinguish in such a way between the two modes, and couldn't. Because as I think of it, if you do support those non-standard names, you are probably translating all names to the same mechanics, and the rest is just syntax which is compiled into that mechanic. So . syntax and [] should be all the same after compilation. But obviously something is going the other way around here...

Without looking at V8's source code, could anyone think of a really satisfying answer? (Think of it as an exercise :-))

[Here's also a quick jsperf.com example](http://jsperf.com/property-dash-parformance)

Thanks to NDM for the jsperf example!

> **Edit:**
>
> To clarify, of course I want also a concrete answer from the real code
>   (which I already found) or to be more precise - the reason behind that
>   specific implementation. That is one of the reasons I asked you to
>   look at it "as an exercise", to look behind the technical
>   implementation and try to find the reason.
>
> But I also wanted to see how other people's minds work in cases like these.
>   This may sound "vague" to some of you - but it is very useful to try and think
>   like other people from time to time, or take their point of view. It
>   enhances your own ways of thinking.

Comment: Amazing question. V8 has a backing class mechanism that will attempt to pair a standard C++ class to objects to speed things up. It might be -it seems, in fact- that when the syntax is non-standard this backing class cannot be built, so Chrome handle the property in a standard way (hash-table most probably).

Comment: I've added a jsperf test and linked it in your question. FYI on my chrome it was 6% slower. In FF they were equally fast, but 7 times faster than chrome!

Comment: I think that this question is at risk of closure due mostly to the *"without looking at V8's source code [...] think of it as an exercise"* line. This is an interesting question, but that line encourages speculation instead of concrete answers, and that is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Why is this closed? There is a very simple and logical answer to this and I have answered many such questions before without any problem. Please reopen.

Comment: @GameAlchemist I would have actually accepted yours as the answer as it is the closest to the answer I wanted, but you only responded as a comment, what a shame :-)

Comment: @daniel.gindi but that's not true at all what he said. They don't use C++ class mechanism but raw memory directly. And there is not a limitation with non-identifier names, they just eagerly assume you want to a hash table if you use non-identifiers names which is true most of the time.

Comment: @Esailija I'm actually torn between you two; That's because of you answered correctly and out of V8 knowledge, which is less of what I wanted, and he answered "roughly", without V8 knowledge, but demonstrating an idea of how an implementation would cause this effect, and gives an average programmer the ability to make good coding decisions. Is there a way to accept two answers ? :-)

Comment: @daniel.gindi Well I don't understand. You wanted someone to speculate a random reason that doesn't make sense rather than the real reason? That is not how Stackoverflow works at all and I start to understand why this was originally closed.

Comment: @Esailija Not exactly, I apologize for not explaining myself correctly. I AM interested in the correct answer, but as I was first trying to think of a reason for that strange behavior that I encountered, and it took me some time to come to a conclusion and finally dive into the actual code - I wanted to see how other people's minds work in cases like these. This may sound "vague" to you - but it is very useful to try and think like other people from time to time, or take their point of view. It enhances your own ways of thinking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So JS objects can be used for two conflicting purposes. They can be used as objects but they can be used as hash tables too. However what is fast and makes sense
for objects is not so for hash tables, so V8 tries to guess what a given object is.

Some signs the user can give that he wants a dictionary are deleting a property or [giving a property a name that cannot be accessed using dot notation](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/9bdbbc29b41c496f7fd68f75ad6c1f2d78df0f87/src/objects.cc#L8015).

Some other heuristics are also used, I have made a gist https://gist.github.com/petkaantonov/6327915.

There is however [a really cool hack](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/9bdbbc29b41c496f7fd68f75ad6c1f2d78df0f87/src/objects.cc#L9593) that redempts an object from hash table hell:

```
function ensureFastProperties(obj) {
    function f() {}
    f.prototype = obj;
    return obj;
}
```

See it in action: http://jsperf.com/property-dash-parformance/2.

The redempted object is not as fast as the original because the properties are stored in the external properties array rather than in-object. But that's still far better than hash table. Note that this is still pretty broken benchmark, do not think for a second that hash tables are only 2x slower than inobject properties.

Comment: The cool hack doesn't seem to work in `Chrome 30.0.1599.65 beta-m`

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 yea need to investigate.. the code to optimize the object in prototype assignment is still there even on most bleeding edge v8